# PIL Module / Could not initialize images API

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm running OSX and Python 2.7. The app I have requires the PIL module, which gives me this error when I try to install it.

I've tried several installations but nothing seems to do the trick. How do I get this to work?

```
WARNING  2012-04-18 18:15:54,222 dev_appserver.py:3394] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was uninstalling everything and then using pip install pil.